# Replace all -1 in numpy array with values from another array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, optimization

I have two numpy arrays, e. g.:

```
x = np.array([4, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

I would like to replace all `-1` in `x` with numbers in `y`, that are not in `x`. First `-1` with first number in `y` that is not in `x` (`3`), second `-1` with second number in `y` that is not in `x` (`5`), ... So final `x` should be:

```
[4 3 1 5 6 2]
```

I created this function:

```
import numpy as np
import time

start = time.time()

def fill(x, y):
    x_i = 0
    y_i = 0

    while x_i < len(x) and y_i < len(y):
        if x[x_i] != -1: # If current value in x is not -1.
            x_i += 1
            continue

        if y[y_i] in x: # If current value in y is already in x.
            y_i += 1
            continue

        x[x_i] = y[y_i] # Replace current -1 in x by current value in y.


for i in range(10000):
    x = np.array([4, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2])
    y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    fill(x, y)

end = time.time()
print(end - start) # 0.296
```

It's working, but I need run this function many times (e. g. milion times), so I would like to optimize it. Is there any way?

Comment: Does the order of the numbers you get from `y` matter?

Comment: How should this array `x = np.array([4, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1])` be replaced (assuming the same `y`) ?

Comment: What happens if you have less numbers than the times -1 appears?

Comment: There are always enough numbers in y. There is no need to solve other cases.

Comment: @ashiswin Yes, order is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([4, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

# create set of choices
sx = set(x)
choices = np.array([yi for yi in y if yi not in sx])

# assign new values
x[x == -1] = choices[:(x == -1).sum()]

print(x)
```

**Output**

```
[4 3 1 5 6 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y_not_in_x = np.setdiff1d(y, x)
x_eq_neg1 = x == -1
n_neg1s = np.sum(x_eq_neg1)
x[x_eq_neg1] = y_not_in_x[:n_neg1s]
```